# Binding data Angular2 ui-router between component <=> parent state <=> child state

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-material2

Here's the gist of what I'm trying to do. I have a header component with a Dark/Light theme for Angular2 Material. The header component lives inside of the 'main' state. I have a nested <ui-view> tag, where my main.home and other main.child states will live. When I toggle the isDarkTheme, main gets it, with a [class.mg2-darkTheme]="isDarkTheme"  toggle works, but gut the children living in main. do not, and their themes do not change.

/*** If there is another approach, I'd be happy to hear it, but I've been trying by using my AngularJS1.x skills, trying to two-way bind the data between parent and child, with no success as of yet... ***/

Passing data in AngularJS1.x and ui-router was extremely intuitive. Just resolve an object, or even better, grab $scope.$parent.main and you could access the entire parent on child routes, 2-way bound. Angular2 and ui-router are a bit challenging.

Documentation I'm finding on ui-router https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/  just point to route params. But I'm not navigating to an :id. I just want to bind data between parent <=> child (just a simple boolean toggle).

I'm trying to pass data (the boolean of ...isDarkTheme) from a component 'header-menu' in the parent 'main' state to the parent 'main' itself, and then down to the child state 'main.home'.

The 'main.component' has a isDarkTheme boolean, which is @Input to the 'header-menu.component', toggled there, and back to main.

header-menu.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'header-menu',
    templateUrl: './header-menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../shared/material-theme.scss', './header-menu.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderMenuComponent {
    // this is set in main and passed in as attr in main.html
    @Input() headerIsDarkTheme: boolean;
    // guessing I pass this bool back out with emitter...
    @Output() themeOnClicked = new EventEmitter<boolean>;
    notifyParentTheme(): void {
        this.headerIsDarkTheme = !this.headerIsDarkTheme;
        this.notifyParentTheme.emit(this.headerIsDarkTheme);
    }
}
```

header-menu.component.html:

```
<div [class.mg2-darkTheme]='headerIsDarkTheme'>..</div>
<button (click)="notifyParentTheme()"
```

main.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'main-cmp', 
    templateUrl: './main.component.ts',
    styleUrls: ['../shared/material-theme.scss']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit { 
    isDarkTheme: boolean;

    NgOnInit(){
        // initializing here... perhaps a better place to init...
        this.isDarkTheme = false;
    }
    listenForTheme( isDarkTheme: boolean ): void {
        this.isDarkTheme = isDarkTheme;

    /****************************************
    *   MAIN QUESTION
    *  How do I pass this theme down to the main.home state?
    *  
    ****************************************/    
    }
}
```

main.component.html:

```
<div [class.mg2-darkTheme]="isDarkTheme">

  <!-- pass in isDarktheme from 'main' into header-menu, header receives with headerIsDarkTheme -->
  <!-- receive toggled theme from header-menu, event (notifyParentTheme) gets the event, then sends to method processHeaderTheme( $event ) -->
  <header-menu [ headerIsDarkTheme ]="isDarkTheme"
              ( themeOnClicked )="listenForTheme( $event )">
  </header-menu>

  <!-- I want to pass this into the ui-view to toggle the theme -->
  <!-- WHY? because the Angular2 Material theme doesn't work in ui-view -->
  <!-- But darkThem works just using a component like <home-cmp></home-cmp> -->
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

main.home.component.html:

```
<div [class.mg2-darkTheme]="homeIsDarkTheme">...</div>
```

main.home.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'home-cmp',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent { 
    @Input() homeIsDarkTheme: boolean;
}
```

states.ts

```
...
export const mainState = { 
  name: 'main',
  // url: '/main',
  component: MainComponent
}; 
export const homeState = { 
    name: 'main.home',
    url: '/home',
    component: HomeComponent
};
```

router.config.ts

```
import {UIRouter} from "ui-router-ng2";
import {Injector, Injectable} from "@angular/core";

 /** UIRouter Config  */
export function uiRouterConfigFn(router: UIRouter, injector: Injector) {
    // If no URL matches, go to the `hello` state by default
    router.urlService.rules.otherwise({ state: 'main' });
}
```

app.module.ts
    ....
    const INITIAL_STATES =  [ 
        mainState,
        homeState
    ];

```
imports: [...
    UIRouterModule.forRoot({ 
      states: INITIAL_STATES,
      useHash: true,
      config: uiRouterConfigFn
    })...
```

Comment: Your title is : "Passing date Angular2 ui-router parent to child NOT with params", But there's no mention of date or router in your code. Did you mean "Passing data from parent to child" ? Please explain better the behavior you want and providing a plunker may help..

Comment: Added routing code. Simply need to get a booloean from a component to the parent state 'main', (KEY) down into 'main.home' which lives in <ui-view>

Comment: See the main.component.ts comment block plz, thx!

Answer (score -1):

Ok, if I understand what your trying to do:
MainComponent provide the initial `isDarkTheme` and listen to HeaderMenuComponent for change

```
//MainComponent html
 <header-menu [ headerIsDarkTheme ]="isDarkTheme"
              ( themeOnClicked )="listenForTheme( $event )">
  </header-menu>

//MainComponent
isDarkTheme: boolean = false; //you can initialize isDarkTheme here

listenForTheme( isDarkTheme: boolean ): void {
        this.isDarkTheme = isDarkTheme; 
    }
```

HeaderMenuComponent get `headerIsDarkTheme` and notify main for any change :

```
//HeaderMenuComponent html
<button (click)="notifyParentTheme()">Notify Parent</button>

//HeaderMenuComponent
@Input() headerIsDarkTheme: boolean;

@Output() themeOnClicked = new EventEmitter<boolean>; //you'll emit a boolean not a type headerIsDarkTheme
notifyParentTheme(): void {
        this.headerIsDarkTheme = !this.headerIsDarkTheme;
        this.themeOnClicked.emit(this.headerIsDarkTheme); //change notifyParentTheme to themeOnClicked
    }
```

**Edit**: So your main question is how do you pass headerIsDarkTheme to HomeComponent.

```
//HomeComponent html
<div [class.mg2-darkTheme]="homeIsDarkTheme">...</div>
```

It seems like you don't have direct interaction between HomeComponent and MainComponent, so the input in HomeComponent is useless

```
export class HomeComponent { 
    @Input() homeIsDarkTheme: boolean;//you can't get your theme with this input
}
```

I recommend you to [create a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service). Your code is little messy (no offense), creating a service will be more readable.

That said, if you want to persist with Input and Output, create a direct relation between Home and Main and emit the value from Main. Something like:

So you don't need any router here... If this answer don't work as you want, I highly recommend you to provide a plunker

Comment: It seems like you don't have direct relation between Main and HomeComponent, so I recommend you to create a service (see my updated answer for more details)

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. Doesn't really answer the question though. In AngularJS ui-router, you can directly access the parent with $scope.parent.&lt;name&gt;.  The relation is exactly the routing. That is want ui-router provides - view nesting and data inheritance. Cheers!

Comment: yes, but this is angular 2 ;). Anyway, wait for better answer then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. From what I'm seeing so far on Stack Overflow and angular.io, it looks that rework into Angular's own router and routerOutlet may be a better choice for me -- since they also now support nested child views.   Much appreciated again!